# Undefined control sequence argument

Tags: macros, errors

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwData{Candidates}{candidates}
\SetKwData{Links}{links}
\SetKwData{Visited}{visited}
\SetKwData{URL}{URL}
\SetKwData{TraversalDepth}{traversalDepth}
\SetKwFunction{RetrieveByTraversal}{retrieveByTraversal}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{Starting page URL, Traversal parameter traversalDepth, Set of visited pages Visited, Already retrieved pages Candidates}
\Output{School list page candidates}
\BlankLine
\Candidates $= \emptyset$\;
\Visited $= \emptyset$\;
\Candidates = \Candidates $\cup$ \URL\;
\Links = Retrieve all but media type links from \URL\;
\Visited = \Visited $\cup$ \Links\;
\ForEach{link $link$ in \Links} {
   %\RetrieveByTraversal($link$, \TraversalDepth-1, \Visisted, \Candidates)\;
}
return \Candidates\;
\caption{Retrieving School List Page Candidates Using Traversal}
\label{algo_traversal_s}
\end{algorithm}
```

I got an undefined control sequence argument error at the commented-out line. When it is commented out, everything works fine. I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with that line.

**Edit**: as requested, I'm posting a minimum working example and the corresponding error message.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[indent,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[algochapter,linesnumbered,noend,ruled,oldcommands]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwData{Candidates}{candidates}
\SetKwData{Links}{links}
\SetKwData{Visited}{visited}
\SetKwData{URL}{URL}
\SetKwData{TraversalDepth}{traversalDepth}
\SetKwFunction{Union}{Union}
\SetKwFunction{RetrieveByTraversal}{retrieveByTraversal}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{Starting page URL, Traversal parameter traversalDepth, Set of visited pages Visited, Already retrieved pages Candidates}
\Output{School list page candidates}
\BlankLine
\Candidates $= \emptyset$\;
\Visited $= \emptyset$\;
\Candidates = \Candidates $\cup$ \URL\;
\Links = Retrieve all but media type links from \URL\;
\Visited = \Visited $\cup$ \Links\;
\ForEach{link $link$ in \Links} {
   \RetrieveByTraversal($link$, \TraversalDepth-1, \Visisted, \Candidates)\;
}
return \Candidates\;
\caption{Retrieving School List Page Candidates Using Traversal}
\label{algo_traversal_s}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding error message is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ink$, \TraversalDepth -1, \Visisted 
                                                  , \Candidates )\; 
l.45 }

?
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. — Class? Package? Algorithms? The error message also tells you which macro was found undefined (the last one on the line).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your advice. MWE added.

Comment: I think you made a type: Visisted instead of visited. with two time s...

Comment: The code is still far from minimal; you load way too many packages!

Comment: The `<argument>` simply means that TeX was reading an argument when it found the error, the undefined command is always the last one on the next line of the error message: `\Visisted` here. (Why we always ask for exact copy of error message not a "description" of the error:-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typing mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply made a typo:

It should be `\Visited` instead of `\Visisted`

Comment: *You* made a typo. ;)

Comment: One becomes hopeless when too enthusiastic ... :(